# JZ0SJ: Metadata accessor information was not found on this database.

Tags: sybase

The complete message is:

```
(JZ0SJ: Metadata accessor information was not found on this database. 
Please install the required tables as mentioned in the jConnect documentation
```

The server is

```
Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 18380 SMP ESD#3/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/asear155/2531/64-bit/FBO/Fri Jan 14 07:04:05 2011
```

Google search does not turn up definite answer to the problem. A lof of result are rather dated too. I checked the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/pdf/prjdbc0700.pdf) but it does not mention any tables.

What is the root cause of this problem? At the very least I would like to see a list of the required tables somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a login problem. The login's password has expired.

The error message is misleading.